# Is this question possible in this section?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask how people would improve the View and Edit Code by Using Peek Definition of Visual Studio. Or how people use it or a similar question. Resharper and the other plugins I tried cannot handle this functionality.

I would like to explain why I feel this need.

I think VS is one of the best editors for writing code in .net. But I also think it's not completely mature. I always get lost trying to follow the code from one class to the other. And I think productivity in software development is really low compared to others sectors like the building of an auto (think to the concept of a pipeline).

Modifying a single functionality in code may require to go ahead and back between 5 or 10 files. Which makes people become dumb :-p

I would like to "exploit" (I don't know a better English word) a so strong community to lead some improvements to the process and the tools we actually use. I know very well that this community has a Q&A style. To me it simply means that I have to cheat the way I express to conciliate my constructive purpose with the limitations imposed by the self-imposed rules of this community. Also I think the rules are here to serve this community, not to limit it. But I have just to accept if the people who administer it doesn't share my point of view.

However, the ideal solution could be that an interface, DTO and unit test would automatically change as the developer change the implementation. But this is too advanced to be proposed, even for a company like microsoft.

It's really easy to propose a new feature to microsoft: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

My final question is: can I simply open the question saying: "how do you avoid to get lost while implementing a changement in the code through many windows in visual studio? Resharper and the other plugins I tried cannot handle this functionality. "

But I also appreciate suggestions and critics.

[image]

Comment: a question like this would be quite unclear / [lacking research](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) without clarifying whether Resharper can handle this or why Resharper is not an option

Comment: @gnat: I've Resharper 8.2 installed already but I couldn't find nothing which would solve my problem. I've also tried other similar software but I could not find nothing solving the problem. I've modified my question specifying that I tried Resharper (I gave it as understood at first).

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> Is this question possible in this section?
>   I would like to ask how people would improve the View and Edit Code by Using Peek Definition of Visual Studio. Or how people use it or a similar question.

And the short answer is "No, it's not possible" on Programmers.

The crux of the question your propose is a poll.  Polls aren't a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A format.

That doesn't mean your main question is bad.  It just means it doesn't fit here or on SE in general.

---

The other part of your question:

> My final question is: can I simply open the question saying: "How do you avoid getting lost while implementing a change in code across many windows in visual studio?"

Is also going to be off-topic as it is too broad.  A good answer could easily take an entire book to write, and that's outside of the Q&A scope that StackExchange seeks to serve.  Complex refactoring is a big topic as evidenced by [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052), [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201485672), or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321127420).

Comment: Thanks. I've better qualified my question at the end, can you have a look also to this part? My final question is: can I simply open the question saying: "how do you avoid to get lost while implementing a changement in the code through many windows in visual studio?"; this would be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to think how to narrow my question. +1 for the help.